# why it fails when I declare a function to invoke in controller

Tags: angularjs

It will fail to bind data from http response if you uncomment "//" line,why? It should be the same, right?

```
var m = angular.module('users', []);

m.controller('UserList', function($scope) {

//  $scope.getdata = function() {

        var u = "http://wisebe.duapp.com/admin?queryusers";
        var userList = this;
        var body = {
            activityid: "10",
            checkin: $('#checkin').val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            url: u,
            type: "post",
            async: false,
            data: body,
            success: function(data) {
                userList.users = data;
            }
        });
//  };

//  $scope.getdata();

    $('#checkin').change(function() {
//      $scope.$apply();
    });

});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "fail"? BTW `$scope.getdata = function() {...}` doesn't return any value, is this the problem?

Comment: I think your query string does not send any values. Please check your URL is correct or not.

Comment: mrak is right. I forgot to return data,sorry:(